# What is the simplest way to use multipart/form-data in AFNetworking 2.0? ios7

Tags: ios7, request, multipart, afnetworking-2

I need to send all my forms on server, firstly text forms and then images. Do someone working with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation page](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/) of `AFNetworking` shows the following example:

**Multi-Part Request**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.png"];
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```